# How to pass array values in jmeter as CSV data config?

Tags: jmeter

Need help for the following scenario:
I have a Csv file with multiple records where one of the parameter is in array format and other detail in the row are plain text.How can it fetch all the data's from csv and send a POST request in jmeter?
Here is my file format below, But it is encoded with special characters. I have given
[CSV file sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zYIT.png)

[Jmeter Response if delimiter set as Comma](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4dNt.png)

[Jmeter Response id delimiter set to | (pipe line/vertical bar line)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5j7c.png)

Answer (score 0):

If your CSV file looks like:

```
[{"A_name":"UserA","A_poid":"12345678","A_Cycle":"1","A_amount":980.00}]|1357902468|16-06-2020 12:58
```

and you configure [CSV Data Set Config](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733689-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG) like:

[image]

You will be able to refer the values from the CSV file as `${column1}`, `${column2}` and `${column3}` where required, i.e. in [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler parameters

[image]

The real data you're sending can be viewed using "Request" tab of the [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener (you might want to switch to "HTTP" mode)

[image]

Comment: Hi Dmitri, Thanks for your quick response. I have already configured the HTTP Request and CSV data config as you have mentioned. I want to know how to modify the CSV File in the format you mentioned? I tried to create CSV, with column 1 have the entire response with delimiter but it doesn't work.[{"A_name":"UserA","A_poid":"12345678","A_Cycle":"1","A_amount":980.00}]|1357902468|16-06-2020 12:58

Comment: I still have the incorrect response 1 with spl characters in it.
POST data:
name=%C3%AF%C2%BB%C2%BF%22%5B%7B%22%22A_name%22%22%3A%22%22UserA%22%22%2C%22%22A_poid%22%22%3A%22%2212345678%22%22%2C%22%22A_Cycle%22%22%3A%22%221%22%22%2C%22%22A_amount%22%22%3A980.00%7D%5D&smc=1357902468&Time=16-06-2020+12%3A58%22%2C%2C